# What does 12 pixels font size in CSS mean?

Tags: css, fonts

Let's say I have a font size of 12 pixels in CSS. The resulting height of the text when measured is a bit more than 12 pixels (about 14 pixels depends on the browser). My question is:

1. Where does the extra space come from?
2. I'm guessing the extra few pixels come from the leading, is that true? If it is, I've set line-height to 0, so that should remove any leading. But that didn't change the result.

text is a SVG element. I'm trying to measure the height of an SVG text element for a given font size, ie: the parameter font_size. In this measurement, the zoom is 1 (no zooming).

```
    function measureSize(text, font_size, zoom, style) {
    $('#container').css('transform', 'scale(' + zoom + ')');
    $('#container').css('transform-origin', 'left top 0px');


    $('#text').text(text).attr('style', 'position: absolute;' + (style || "")).css('font-size', font_size + 'px');

    var bbox = $('#text')[0].getBBox();     
    return { width: bbox.width, height: bbox.height };
};
```

Comment: How are you measuring the text? Are you measuring the glyphs, the line box, the containing block, or something else?

Comment: The extra pixels come from text rendering. If you turn off all text rendering and such technologies like ClearType in Windows, the line height will be the 12 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of an inline element depends on many things, including the font and the browser. The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-CSS21-20070719/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) explicitly leaves this up to browsers. Setting `line-height` to 1 removes the leading (or sets the leading to 0, depending on your meaning for “leading” – the terminology is confusing), but browsers may still make the line box taller than the font size.

If you set `display: block` or `display: inline-block` on the element, you can then set `height: 1em` to make its height equal the size of the font. This may imply that some parts of characters (especially diacritic marks, as in “Ê” or “Å”) get cut off.